# Download Source files of a specific directory under Azure DevOps Git Monorepo

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have a Git monorepo which has two folders (two separate solutions) in it. I have set two CI builds for each solution. Each CI has the `Enable Continuous Integration` activated. For each CI pipeline, I have specified `Path filters` (Exclude) for each folder so as to prevent CI builds for any commit for the other folder.

Is there a way for the private agent to download **ONLY** the source files [under a folder] which got affected by a commit?

[image]

That is, when the *Database* folder gets a commit, the agent downloads only the source files under the *Database* folder.

Is this related to `Checkout submodules`?

**UPDATE**

This is my PowerShell script:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

git config --global user.email "my_email_here"
git config --global user.name "my_username_here"

git init
git remote add origin -f https://my_username_here@dev.azure.com/my_username_here/TxProject/_git/testtwoprojects
git config core.sparseCheckout true
Set-Content -Path .git/info/sparse-checkout -Value "Source/*"
git pull origin master
```

The error I receive is:

> git : fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered. At
>   C:\agent_work_temp\b5feb3b7-f104-48a0-94d8-a8c769e84a6e.ps1:8 char:1
>   + git remote add origin -f https://my_username_here@dev.azure.com/my_username_here/TxProjec ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: InvalidO...on encountered.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   PowerShell exited with code '1'.

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution. First I changed to a Command Line task (from PowerShell) and added `2>&1` at the end of the commands.

Final code is:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

git config --global user.email "user_email"
git config --global user.name "user_name"

git init
git remote add origin -f LINK_TO_REPO 2>&1
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo Source/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in Azure DevOps, where there is a change in a file all the repo is been downloaded to the agent.

As a workaround, you can disable the option to download the repository and add the first task that downloads the folder with `sparse-checkout`.

To disable the downloading of the repo go to Get Sources and check "Don't sync sources":

[image]

A PowerShell script that uses `sparse-checkout` to download only one folder:

```
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true 
git remote add origin -f $(Build.Repository.Uri)
$commit = "$(Build.SourceVersion)"
# Get the folder name from the git commit info - maybe will not work always, need to improve it
$folder = (((git show $commit)[6] -split 'a/')[1] -split '/')[0]
Set-Content -Path .git/info/sparse-checkout -Value "$folder/*"
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. In case I use the PowerShell script generated in the temp folder [of the agent] locally it works perfectly. However within the pipeline I'm receiving an error. Please find my updated original post.

Comment: @naregkar try to enable the OAuth token (in the job options)

Comment: Already had enabled that with no luck. I believe it is from this line: `git remote`

Comment: Solved it, if you want, check my initial post for the solution. Thanks a lot!